# Visual Studio Code Remote Edit files on server

Tags: visual-studio-code, sftp

Looking for a way to remotely edit files on a server, without downloading the entire website locally first.

I've seen they have their remote - ssh plugin, which looks more complicated than what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to have a terminal or some other ssh program running while doing this. That just feels like an extra step.

Then there's ftp-simple which looks good but it downloads the entire website on to my computer! This is not what I'm looking for.

The ideal extension would let you set up a bunch of hosts + authentication in a config file, and then you can just select from them. A good example is the remote-browser extension, but it lacks features like creating files and folders.

I was using ftp-remote-edit on atom, which does exactly what I'm looking for, but I just found out Atom has been sunset so I probably shouldn't continue using it :(
https://github.com/h3imdall/ftp-remote-edit

Another good example is NotePadd++'s NppFTP plugin, but ideally would like to use a nicer IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution! Pulsar, which is Atom's successor maintained by community support. I can just use the same plugin I've been using on Atom :)

https://pulsar-edit.dev/